# Latex error- file 'fancyvrb.sty' not found

Tags: miktex, texniccenter, fancyvrb

I am using Miktex2.9 and Texniccenter and error is coming 'fancyvrb.sty' not found, so what to do can i download it , if yes after downloading where to put the file so that after running the texniccenter it finds the file. Please help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have to investigate the documenation of updating MikTeX